# Async await in mysql seeding does not run

Tags: mysql, reactjs, async-await, sequelize.js

I am trying to seed my MySQL database. I am using the Sequelize ORM. In my index.js file which is in the models folder, I have the code to run the realSync() function for every model as such :

```
const syncDB = async () => {
await db['Meal'].realSync();
await db['User'].realSync();
}
syncDB();
```

And in my 'Meal' file, I have the following:

```
const mealSeeds = require("../scripts/mealSeeds");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
let Meal = sequelize.define("Meal", {
id: {
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true
},
name: DataTypes.STRING,
type: DataTypes.STRING,
description: DataTypes.STRING,
photo_URL: DataTypes.STRING,
allergen_dairy: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_treenuts: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_peanuts: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_wheat: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_fish: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_crustaceanshellfish: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_eggs: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
allergen_soya: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
date_available: DataTypes.DATE,
time_available: DataTypes.TIME,
quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
zipcodes: DataTypes.JSON,
catererId: {
field: "CatererId",
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
allowNull: true,
defaultValue: 0
}
})
Meal.associate = function (models) {
Meal.belongsTo(models.User, {
foreignKey: "catererId",
targetKey: "id"
})

}
// // Insert the meal seed data
Meal.realSync = async () => {
await Meal.sync()
return await Meal.bulkCreate(mealSeeds,
{ignoreDuplicates: true}
);
};
return Meal;
}
```

Where the Meal.realSync is supposed to seed the Meals table with data from the mealSeeds.js file in the scripts directory. (And I have a User.js file with the user table fields and a similar .realSync() function for the User table. And this function is working just fine, and users are being seeded into the db).

This function was working fine for weeks, as I was building the project, and recently after changing some of the fields in the 'Meal' table, it no longer works. My previous research shows that by calling the realSync() function asynchronously in the index.js file, it will run and wait for the Meal realSync() function to complete before running the User realSync() function. I am not sure why it no longer runs the first function at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved-I figured out that my seed data did not contain a foreign key reference.